# Copy many large tables to another database

Tags: sql-server

**What I have to do**

> I need to copy the data of a lot of tables (over 500) from a
> production database to a pre-production database, to better test our
> systems before deployment.
>
> A lot of those tables are quite small, but some of them are very
> large, the largest has currenly around 55 million rows, but grows
> somewhat fast.

**What a coworker suggested**

> A coworker was doing something similar in a test environment, and
> developed a script to do this, which basically did:
>
> ```
> TRUNCATE [TableName1]
>
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TableName1] ON
>
> INSERT INTO [TableName1] (Col1, Col2,...) SELECT (Col1, Col2,...) FROM [TableName2]
>
> SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TableName1] OFF
> ```
>
> And did this for around 30 tables he was running tests on. I tried to
> start with this approach, but when I tested with the first table (the
> 55 million rows one), it's just taking too long.

**What is different between my coworkers' case and mine**

> I see 2 differences between what my coworker did and what I have to
> do:
>
> - The largest table he worked with was far smaller than the largest one we have.
> - All the tables he was copying from and copying to were on the same server, but I have to copy the tables from one server to another.

**What I've tried**

> I first tried using Linked servers, and it seems to work since I see
> no error, but it's taking forever, and my boss wants this task to be
> performed every two weeks at night, so it's unfeasible for it to take
> so long.

Which would be the most efficient way to copy over 500 large tables to another database, hopefully in less than two hours?

Comment: Why he TRUNCATE before INSERT? 
This way you are going to copy the structure of the table but not the data

Comment: He truncates on [Table1], which is my preproduction, and the insert gets the data from [Table2], which wasn't truncated.

Comment: Arrived at this point, given the complexity, you can start building a proper ETL process with SSIS

Answer (score 3):

Database backup and restoration is safest method to achieve what you are looking for.

You may use compression method and stripe(multiple files) to make size of your backup smaller and then copy the backup file to your second server and restore it.

You may also use bulk copy(BCP) for copying however that will again be at table level and not at database level.

Please also make a note of one important point - In case, you have any foreign key constraints on these tables, you need to copy them in the right sequence otherwise it would fail.

To avoid all these issues, backup and restoration is the most reliable, safest and fastest method.

Database backup contains all indexes, constraints and every objects inside database, it will be part of one bundle called database backup and you can restore it on second server.

Comment: Would this present no issue (or take too long) with indexes and constraints?

Comment: No, all indexes, constraints and all objects inside database will be part of one bundle called database backup and you can restore it on second server. About the size, I have suggested to use compression method and stripe. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

1. Right click on the database > Tasks > Export Data...
2. In Choose Data Source set `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`
   [image]
3. Do the same for the Choose a Destination
4. Select Copy data form one or more tables or views

...and execute

[image]

Comment: All good unless you have foreign key constraint.

Comment: Good point. What about Tasks > Export Data-tier Application... ? That is used for migration to Azure too and keeps constraints. Otherwise Transactional Replication could be an option?